# Multiple OkHttp newCall not executing at once

Tags: android, get, okhttp

So I will be making multiple GET requests and would love for them to execute all at once. However, as it is right now I have to hit the sign in button twice for the second newCall to go off. I would prefer if more newCall went off. But looking at it, the second newCall needs the response from the first one before it can. Is there a way that once the first gets the response, the second one executes instead of having to hit the sign in button twice?

Button code:

```
SignInButton signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button);
        signInButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (authPreferences.getUser() != null && authPreferences.getToken() != null) {
                    System.out.println(authPreferences.getToken());
                    doCoolAuthenticatedStuff();
                    try {
                        run();
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    //new RetrieveFeedTask().execute();
                } else {
                    chooseAccount();
                }
            }
        });
```

run() code

```
public void run() throws Exception {
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url(API_URL + authPreferences.getToken())
                .build();

        client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


            public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                if (!response.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + response);

                Headers responseHeaders = response.headers();
                for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                    System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                }
                try
                {
                    String token = response.body().string();
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(token);
                    commatoken = json.getString("access_token");
                } catch (JSONException e)
                {

                }
//                commatoken = response.body().string();
//                System.out.println(commatoken);
            }

        });

        final Request dataRequest = new Request.Builder()
                .header("content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .header("authorization", "JWT "+ commatoken)
                .url(ChffrMe_URL).build();

        client.newCall(dataRequest).enqueue(new Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call call, Response responseMe) throws IOException {
                if (!responseMe.isSuccessful()) throw new IOException("Unexpected code " + responseMe);

                Headers responseHeaders = responseMe.headers();
                for (int i = 0, size = responseHeaders.size(); i < size; i++) {
                    System.out.println(responseHeaders.name(i) + ": " + responseHeaders.value(i));
                }
                try
                {
                    String myInfo = responseMe.body().string();
                    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(myInfo);
                    commaMyInfo = json.getString("points");
                } catch (JSONException e)
                {

                }
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        responseView.setText("Comma Points: " +commaMyInfo);
                    }
                });

                //responseView.setText(responseMe.body().string());
                //System.out.println(responseMe.body().string());
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: why don't you just chain the calls when the first response is successful? call A > response A > successful? > call B

Comment: How would that look? Can you do a new call within a new call?

Comment: extract your 2nd call into a separate method and call it in your first onResponse()?